# how to fix this flutter error unable to download flutter plugin also try from disk but not working

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-studio

[image]please help to solve this error i also reinstalled android studio many times i don't know how to solve this also saw many solution but not working anyone

Comment: Have you installed intellij from flatpak? In that case it's kinda broken (the same is for vsCode). In any case, try do flutter clean and then flutter pub get, maybe something is not right, altough i think it's a problem of IDE. Last, check if there's any update for intellij.